# Object is null but visible on the screen

Tags: java, mouselistener

I am creating a game with a character:

```
p = new Player(200, 200 ,this);
```

then in the MouseListener I say:

```
if(p != null){
        deltaMousePlayerX= (p.getX()- x);
        deltaMousePlayerY= (p.getY() - y );
        System.out.println(deltaMousePlayerX+","+deltaMousePlayerY);
    }
```

The problem is that it didn't print out anything when I clicked so may be p is null?.
how do I fix it?

PS: the character is visible on the screen

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are attaching MouseListener to this Player object.

Comment: Add some more complete code. With these snippets it's hard to say what's going on

Comment: Are you running the application with a text console/DOS window?  Can you see other lines you have printed.  Is the `p` value the same fields or just two fields with the same name?  A field doesn't just change to `null` magically.

Comment: Have you registered the MouseListener with the component?

Comment: I think the best thing to do in this case is remove all of your code in the mouse listener and just have the System.out.println("Test") in the method. This way you'll figure out if you've actually registered/attached the Mouse Listener or if your current code is causing the issue.

Comment: Should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Mostly it is a problem with registering the Listener - whatever it's-